# Docker Exec format error

Tags: bash, docker

I have dockerfile with:
  **ENTRYPOINT ["/code/docker-entrypoint.sh"]**

*docker-entrypoint.sh*

```
!/bin/sh
/code/utils/BrowserStackLocal --key xxx  --daemon  start
robot --outputdir ./logs --variable xxx:yyy --variable     ./tests/BasicTestSuite.robot
/code/utils/BrowserStackLocal --key xxx  --daemon  start
```

When I run image, I am getting error -

```
  /code/docker-entrypoint.sh: 3: /code/docker-entrypoint.sh:  /code/utils/BrowserStackLocal: Exec format error
```

But next command (robot --outputdir ...) successfully running.

What Am I doing wrong?

P.S I've done RUN chmod a+x /code/utils/BrowserStackLocal

Comment: What is the output of `file /code/utils/BrowserStackLocal` ?

Comment: @Aserre Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
It seems that I understand what is wrong - this file is only for MacOS, I need download  this binary for Linux, yes?

Comment: Yes. you can download it from here: https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing#command-line

Comment: Docker will only understand Linux system calls (except for some very specific windows images), so you'll need to provide the correct architecture for the packages you want to add to your containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are executing `BrowserStackLocal` probably has a different architecture than the Docker image you are running.

Are you by any chance running the 32-bits version in a 64-bit enviornment of  [BrowserStackLocal](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing)? You can check with the command file: `file BrowserStackLocal`

The other command runs after the first one fails which is expected.